# How do a keyword search in kibana4 dashboard

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, kibana-4

I have a kibana Dashboard with data table visualization, In that visualization widget, I need to scroll down or change pagination.i have 1800 city name in that single visualization widget, if I want to go to city name starts with K...., it's very hard for me to search for each page
NOTE: I have an not analyzed data.

Comment: i tried city:k*

Comment: Have you tried `city:/K.*/`?

Answer (score 0):

In the search bar at the top, I believe you can use Lucene expressions.

Try:

```
city:K*
```

Comment: but when i search with full string, it works ex: city:MORRISTOWN

Comment: but my requirement is, when i type a string or substring in the search box, it only shows data related to that keyword.

Comment: If you want it to match exactly, use: city:"Kansas City" or whatever string you want to match exactly. You can use regular expressions in place of the "K*" example I provided.

Comment: i already try it, https://www.dropbox.com/home?preview=Screenshot+from+2017-10-11+11%3A02%3A51.png

Comment: Apologies.. I may not be understanding your request fully. The filtering you've shown in this picture is not what you're looking for? Do you just want a sort?

Comment: thanks for your response , when I enter a substring or keyword on my search, it will show only the related data.For example: when I add a keyword " port " in the search, it will show result below link, https://www.dropbox.com/home?preview=Screenshot+from+2017-10-11+13%3A25%3A32.png             but i want to show only the data that contain the keyword "port"

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/xm9c3jpftywumh2/Screenshot%20from%202017-10-11%2013%3A25%3A32.png?dl=0

Comment: Do the documents shown in your most recent example have fields other than the two shown in the screenshots? My guess is that you're seeing these results because you're retrieving a hit on a field not shown here.

What does "city:port" give you, rather than just "port" ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156516/discussion-between-mike-michaels-and-rajesh-a).